# Pyspark using function with when and otherwise

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to use *when* and *otherwise* from PySpark, but instead of using a literal, the final value depends on a specific column. This is some code I've tried:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


def getValueByCountry(country):
    # Possibly some more complex calculations based on country
    if country == "Spain":
        return 1
    else:
        return 2


def getValue(currency):
    # Possibly some more complex calculations based on currency
    if currency == "EUR":
        return 3
    else:
        return 4


currency_column = "Currency"
df = df.withColumn(
    "Value",
    F.when(
        F.col(currency_column).contains("None"), getValueByCountry(F.col("Country"))
    ).otherwise(getValue(F.col(currency_column))),
)
```

And I'm getting this error:

> ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and',
> '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean
> expressions.

From line 'if val == 'Spain':'. Which I guess makes sense because I'm passing the whole column to the function, instead of a specific value at each step.

Is there a simple and efficient way to achieve what I want? I've heard about using UDF, but I've also seen some people concerned about possible perfomance issues, so if there's any easy way to do this without using UDF, I would prefer it. If it's not possible, UDF is fine too.

This is some sample input dataset:

| Currency | Country |
| --- | --- |
| USD | Rusia |
| EUR | Netherland |
| NoneCur | Spain |
| (None) | UK |

And this is the exected output:

| Currency | Country | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USD | Rusia | 4 |
| EUR | Netherland | 3 |
| NoneCur | Spain | 1 |
| (None) | UK | 2 |

Comment: Complete liste of spark functions available in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions). If you cannot perform a task with these functions, then you have to create an UDF.

Comment: The problem with your questions is in this sentence `# Possibly some more complex calculations based on currency`. Depending on the complexity of the task, it can be done with builtin spark function or not, and then you have to write an UDF. But as long as you do not explain exactly what is blocking you, you will only have partial answers.

Comment: @Steven I see... The functions are actually quite complex, so I think the only option might be UDF. I'll take a look at the list you provided, just in case I can somehow compose the whole thing using built in functions... Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Generally, built-in are enough, no matter how complex the business rules are complex. They're enough to manipulate the whole dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following without using a udf :

```py
currency_column = "Currency"
df = df.withColumn(
    "Value",
    F.when(
        F.col(currency_column).contains("None"),
        F.when(F.col("Country") == "Spain", 1).otherwise(2),
    ).otherwise(F.when(F.col("Country") == "Russia", 4).otherwise(3)),
)
```

Although the above may work for the sample provided, you may have more values. As such you could consider using conditional operators:

```py
currency_column = "Currency"
df = df.withColumn(
    "Value",
    F.when(F.col(currency_column).contains("None") & F.col("Country") == "Spain", 1)
    .when(F.col(currency_column).contains("None") & F.col("Country") == "UK", 2)
    .when(F.col(currency_column) == "USD" & F.col("Country") == "Russia", 4)
    .when(F.col(currency_column) == "EUR" & F.col("Country") == "Netherland", 3)
    .otherwise(999),
)
```

where `999` is for conditions you are yet to consider.

More details on spark function when : [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.when.html?highlight=when#pyspark.sql.Column.when)